# Firebase custom token expiration in JavaScript

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Firebase custom authentication using the firebase-admin library in Python on my server.

The first time I use the token, it works fine and I'm able to authenticate.

But if I restart my node.js application a few minutes later, I get the error:

```
The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.
```

Which I believe means that it has expired, even though I never logged out.

This does not seem to be working:

```
Once you've called authWithCustomToken successfully, you stay logged in forever (until you sign out explicitly) so you should be able to get devices to have a long-lived authentication session without minting long-lived custom tokens.
```

How do I explicitly save the authentication between application restarts?  Or do I have to mint a new custom token on every restart?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Custom tokens are only valid for an hour. However, I'd suspect your caught error code to be something different. I'm personally on a quest to figure out how to best keep these tokens refreshed, but I do wonder if a deployed instance restarting might be an alternate cause of tokens being invalidated.